# Why is GPG not working even with pinentry installed?

Tags: macos, gnupg

Despite me installing pinentry, I *still* get the following error:

```
xxxxxxxMacxxxxx:~ MAU$ gpg2 -c --cipher-algo=aes
gpg-agent[89931]: can't connect to the PIN entry module: IPC connect call failed
gpg-agent[89931]: command get_passphrase failed: No pinentry
gpg: problem with the agent: No pinentry
gpg: error creating passphrase: Operation cancelled
gpg: symmetric encryption of `[stdin]' failed: Operation cancelled
```

Comment: Did you restart the agent after installing pinentry?

Comment: @HelmutGrohne As in kill 89931?

Answer (score 5):

I've had that error message when trying to decrypt a (symmetrically encrypted) file on OS X (macOS Sierra 10.12.4). Solution was to add the option `--pinentry-mode loopback`

```
bla$ gpg -d ciphertext.gpg 
gpg: AES encrypted data
gpg: problem with the agent: No pinentry
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key

bla$  gpg --pinentry-mode loopback -d ciphertext.gpg 
gpg: AES encrypted data
Enter passphrase: ...
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
...plaintext...
```

Answer (score 4):

You may have an old (and wrong) entry in your `gpg-agent.conf` file. Check this config file for an incorrect path to the pinentry-program and delete this line.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this after using `sudo -u foo -H bash`, solution was to `ssh localhost` to get a proper fresh environment.

Diffing `env | sort` showed several differences between the two sessions, but modifying the `sudo`ey one to be the same didn't help.  The thing I didn't try was starting XDG.

Possibly the difference is the existence of an XDG session?  (Running Debian mostly-8.10)

Comment: Better answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/378025 : Permissions on the terminal in use.  Why doesn't it give a better error?

Answer (score -6):

on macOS, removing my local .gnupg configuration and retrying worked.

**Warning** This will remove all your keys!

```
rm -rf ~/.gnupg*
```

Comment: It will delete gpg key

Comment: Thank you so much, I spent a fair amount of time on that. As Andrii said this solution is barbaric. In my case, I have my keys and config backed up. I could reimport everything in few seconds

Comment: Oh my god this worked - I didn't have any GPG keys so this was a safe thing to try. Thanks!